# PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key

Tags: 18.10, signature

Hi i just installed ubuntu 18.10 
first boot worked fine but after I reboot

black screen with this message keep comming up

```
PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

I have no idea what this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Try turning off `secure boot` in your BIOS. You've installed software that isn't signed.. like Nvidia?

Comment: @heynnema I have the same issue and secure boot I just double checked is disabled. Not sure if it's related but I have a dual GPU (intel/nvidia) laptop

Comment: @Jonathan It's probably the nvidia drivers. What version are you running? Does the machine still boot/operate?

Comment: Same problem here.... Except I've been running for a few months and just updated packages, and booted to this. Do I really need to disable secure boot just to have a working install?